# Prometheus phantom counter resets

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to compute the rate of events published to a kafka topic. I have a metric `kafka_topic_partition_current_offset` that tracks the max offset for all my topics. This metric only ever increases, except if I were to delete and recreate the topic, which would start it over at 0.

The issue I'm having is that `rate(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset[60s])` is producing massive spikes. I believe this is because it is detecting counter resets where there shouldn't be any.

Below, I've graphed `resets(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset)` next to `kafka_topic_partition_current_offset` with some scaling to bring them into perspective. These counter resets perfectly coincide with `rate(..)` spikes (**not depicted**).

[image]

My understanding is that counter resets are defined by when a counter decreases in value from one sample to the next, but we can clearly see that the yellow line never decreases, so I would expect no counter resets within the depicted interval.

My question is thus **what other reasons would cause prometheus to detect resets?**

More context:

- my default scrape interval is 15s, but these kafka metrics are only scraped every 30s.
- The resets don't disappear if I change the range vectors from `[60s]` to larger values

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem periodically.  I would suggest that you look at

1. your actual counter values
2. the timestamps for your counter datapoints, and
3. the result of resets() over your range

I suspect you'll see that your values and timestamps look fine, but resets() claims there's been reset.  That's what I see when this happens.

I know, not an answer, but it's a starting place for looking into what appears to be a bug.